# Unity raycast possible bug?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

this is my code for raycast in my school project game. If I put script on object everything is working just fine. But if I close Unity and reopen my project, the value of "jakDaleko" = distance stays locked on 1129.395 instead of changing every frame.

What should I change so it will work everytime and not just the first time ipress play button.

Here's my code.

script 1 = raycast

---

```
public class SmerDivani : MonoBehaviour {

public static float VzdalenostOdCile;
public float VzdalenostOdCileInterni;


// Update is called once per frame
void Update() {    
    RaycastHit Hit;
    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward), out Hit)) { 
        VzdalenostOdCileInterni = Hit.distance;
        VzdalenostOdCile = VzdalenostOdCileInterni;
    }
}
```

}

Second script

---

```
public class TabuleMesto1 : MonoBehaviour
{

public float JakDaleko;
public GameObject AkceTlacitko;
public GameObject AkceText;
public GameObject UIQuest;
public GameObject ThePlayer;
public GameObject NoticeCam;

void Update() {
    JakDaleko = SmerDivani.VzdalenostOdCile;
}

void OnMouseOver() {
    if (JakDaleko <= 5) {
        AkceTlacitko.SetActive(true);
        AkceText.SetActive(true);
    }

    if (JakDaleko > 5)
    {
        AkceTlacitko.SetActive(false);
        AkceText.SetActive(false);
    }

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Akce")) {
        if (JakDaleko <= 5) {
            AkceTlacitko.SetActive(false);
            AkceText.SetActive(false);
            UIQuest.SetActive(true);
            NoticeCam.SetActive(true);
            ThePlayer.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
}

void OnMouseExit() { 
    AkceTlacitko.SetActive(false);
    AkceText.SetActive(false);
}


}
```

Comment: Just a side note: in C# like in every other programming language, it's common practice to name all identifiers in English. A developer reading `JakDaleko = SmerDivani.VzdalenostOdCile` has no idea what this thing does, if he/she doesn't know your language.

Comment: @dymanoid Thank you. I will try to write everything in ENG.

Comment: Additionally, what's the point of both `VzdalenostOdCile` and `VzdalenostOdCileInterni`? One's static, and I see that static usage, but why are you doing it that way? Is `VzdalenostOdCileInterni` used anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve? Maybe this should "fix" your problem, you're not clearing the distance if the raycast don't hits....

```
void Update() {   

    RaycastHit Hit;
    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, out Hit)) { 
        VzdalenostOdCileInterni = Hit.distance;   
    }
    else {
        VzdalenostOdCileInterni = 0.0f;
    }
    VzdalenostOdCile = VzdalenostOdCileInterni;
}
```

Additionally I think you should use transform.forward instead of transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward)

Comment: @Draco18s I use instead of debug log. The public value is shown in inspector when i test the game

Answer (score 0):

I think that the biggest problem was the name of the file. For some reason, my stupidity included, the solution was to rename the script from table1 to table_1